# How to remember only a username in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

Chrome and Firefox allow to remember only a username (gmail, for example) without no problem.

But it's not working the same way for Safari.

Safari, if remembers, it remembers both, username and password.

But if I don't save password it doesn't remember only a username.

How can I do this?

Couldn't find any related post.

Comment: I believe the only way would be to save the password, then going into the "keychain" application (located in applications -> utilities), finding the entry and manually deleting the password.

Comment: This works. The only drawback is that Safari will forever ask you if you want to update the saved password each time you enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Safari / Preferences - Autofill. Make sure: User names and passwords is selected.

If you don't want your FB pasword saved, open Keychain Access.

Applications/Utilities.

Select Passwords on the left.

Delete the Facebook keychain. (That's where the password is stored).

Now navigate to the Facebook page, enter your log in data but when prompted for Safari to save that data to a new keychain, click Never.